# Error messages not being thrown on new server

Tags: php, upload

```
Array ( [0] => Oops. Your photo's size is 1.76 mb. Max allowed is 1 mb. )
Array ( [0] => Sorry, only jpeg/jpg, gif, and png extensions allowed. )
```

These errors get thrown on our old server...but not on our new server. It just returns the user to the upload page. It does still function as it should...just no 
error messages.

Any ideas what might be the reason for this?

```
Old server: 
upload_max_filesize set to 20M 
post_max_size set to 20M

New server: 
upload_max_filesize set to 2M 
post_max_size set to 2M
```

Test file size: 1.76 mb

Here is the code:

```
 <?php if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   

    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $file_name=strtolower($file_name); 
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '', $file_name); 
    $random_digit=rand(0000000,9999999);
    $file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;

    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","gif","png");      

    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
         $errors[]= "Sorry, only jpeg/jpg, gif, and png extensions allowed.";
        }

    else if ($file_size > 1097152){
        $file_size=$file_size/1048576;
        $errors[]= "Oops. Your photo's size is ".round($file_size,2)." mb.        Max allowed is 1 mb.";
        }

   else if (file_exists("images/" . $file_name))
          {
          echo $file_name . " already exists. ";
          }

    if(empty($errors)==true){

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name)){


    mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE users SET image='$file_name'
    WHERE id LIKE '$id'");
    mysqli_close();

    include "php_image_magician/1.1_resize_basic.php";
            }

        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){ 
    echo "Success";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What type of error messages are enabled on new server? Make it to E-ALL and check once

Comment: No error messages...

Comment: add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` on your php script first line

Comment: Still no error messages. I am getting the proper messages thrown with the old server...with the new server I am getting the "success" message when uploading the same file (1.76 mb)

Comment: ok it is working fine. I assume that the server side checks in php.ini get first priority, and then the php checks...so if the upload_max_filesize checks fail then the php checks will not output?

Comment: Note to the commenters that this is this is not a configuration issue related to error reporting; no PHP error is being triggered. The output is produced by this line: `print_r($errors);` That line only prints if the conditional `empty($errors)==true` is false (in other words, if the `$errors` variable is empty). If the errors are not printed, then the array is empty, and the error conditions in the previous lines are not being triggered.

Comment: The one other (very slight) possibility is that the script has output buffering turned on, and the error output is being produced but not sent to the screen. This is unlikely-- something to consider only after you have double-verified that the `$error` array actually contains data.

Comment: Thanks...it is throwing the errors out properly now, so must have been something to do with the upload_max_filesize settings, the php $file_size allowed, and the size of the file being uploaded.